# How to Export multiple NWC from revit and when append in Navisworks it show sperate Viewpoints?

Tags: revit-api, revit, autodesk-navisworks

Export Multiple NWC (Active 3D view)from Revit and append in Navisworks,
but it show same viewpoint for both NWC .
I think it should show different Viewpoints because we export NWC of different 3D views

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for this at work - you just need to change the Active View in Revit before you run the export command.

Also make sure that the `NavisworksExportOptions.ExportScope` is configured to export the current view.